# Changing tabindex of element before tabbing into it

Tags: javascript, html, focus, tabindex

I'm trying to make my validation to work.

By default, I should not be able to tab into 'second' element.
It is enabled by js function attached to onchange event on the 'first' element.
When I focus 'first', and click `Tab`, I expect that js function will finish and then I'll navigate to the 'second' element.
Instead, I find myself at 'third' element'.

```js
function releaseSecond() {
    document.getElementById('second').tabIndex = 0;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <label for="first">First</label>
    <input type="text" id="first" tabindex="0" onblur="releaseSecond()"/>
    
    <label for="second">Second</label>
    <input type="text" id="second" tabindex="-1"/>
    
    <label for="third">Third</label>
    <input type="text" id="third" tabindex="0"/>
</form>
```

Is it possible to fix this? Is the target of TAB determined before event hooks are invoked?

Comment: Could you not just use `onfocus="releaseSecond()"` instead of onblur

Comment: No, I cannot. Imagine some validation of the input value instead of this dummy function.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use .focus?

```js
function releaseSecond() {
    // After you do your code, then go and focus the second element
    document.getElementById('second').focus();
}
```

```html
<form>
    <label for="first">First</label>
    <input type="text" id="first" tabindex="0" onblur="releaseSecond()"/>
    
    <label for="second">Second</label>
    <input type="text" id="second" tabindex="-1"/>
    
    <label for="third">Third</label>
    <input type="text" id="third" tabindex="0"/>
</form>
```